# cout not printing after reading files

Tags: c++, cout

For some reason my cout isn't working correctly. I think it has something to do with the buffer needing to be flushed. I tried to add a `cout << flush` after reading the files but that didn't fix it. The only place I print is `main()` in the for loop. This is the output I get from those prints.

```
Aeberg
Aaren
Aaron
Full Name
 Aaron
```

Before and after Aaron, there is a space. So only the last name prints.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <queue>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 50000;

void initFirst(string first[]);
void initMiddle(string middle[]);
void initLast(string last[]);

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  ifstream in;
  ofstream out;

  string first[SIZE];
  string middle[SIZE];
  string last[SIZE];

  initFirst(first);
  initMiddle(middle);
  initLast(last);
  string x;

  for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
  {
    cout << first[i] << endl;
    cout << middle[i] << endl;
    cout << last[i] << endl;

    cout << "Full Name" << endl;
    cout << first[i] << " " << middle[i] << " " << last[i] << endl; // Isn't printing correctly here
  }

  return 1;
}

  void
initFirst(string first[])
{
  ifstream file("names.txt");
  string line;
  int counter = 0;

  if(file.is_open())
  {
    while(getline(file, line))
    {
      first[counter] = line;
      counter++;
    }
    file.close();
  }
  int left = SIZE - counter;
  int random[left];

  for(int i = 0; i < left; i++)
    random[i] = rand() % counter;

  for(int i = counter; i < SIZE; i++)
    first[i] = first[random[i-counter]];
}

void
initMiddle(string middle[])
{
  ifstream file("first-names.txt");
  string line;
  int counter = 0;

  if(file.is_open())
  {
    while(getline(file, line))
    {
      middle[counter] = line;
      counter++;
    }
    file.close();
  }

  int left = SIZE - counter;
  int random[left];

  for(int i = 0; i < left; i++)
    random[i] = rand() % counter;

  for(int i = counter; i < SIZE; i++)
    middle[i] = middle[random[i-counter]];
}

void
initLast(string last[])
{
  ifstream file("middle-names.txt");
  string line;
  int counter = 0;

  if(file.is_open())
  {
    while(getline(file, line))
    {
      last[counter] = line;
      counter++;
    }
    file.close();
  }

  int left = SIZE - counter;
  int random[left];

  for(int i = 0; i < left; i++)
    random[i] = rand() % counter;

  for(int i = counter; i < SIZE; i++)
    last[i] = last[random[i-counter]];
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use std::shuffle in <algorithm> if all you want is to shuffle the names. I don't see you maintaining a relationship between the first, middle and last names read from the input files. A shuffle would be much simpler. As to why it is printing the way it is, it is hard to tell....probably your program exhibits UB because of the way you are playing around with the indexes. Not sure.

Comment: I never heard of shuffle. The files are named incorrectly, but all they are is a list of names.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Comment: Something to watch out for: You're throwing at least 150000 `std::strings` on the stack! If your compiler does short string optimization, odds of a stack overflow are pretty good.

Comment: `int random[left];` this is not a supported thing in C++. The value of `left` should be known in compile time for this to have a defined behaviour.

Comment: @Sailesh - Either it is supported or it is not. If it is not then this would have been a compiler error. If he is not getting a compiler error, it means he is using a compiler extension which supports variable length arrays (for ex : - gcc supports VLA). So this can't be classified as exhibiting 'Undefined Behavior' because of that.

Comment: Yeah everything compiles fine no errors. I just compile it ‘g++ file.cpp’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to improve your program a little.

- you don't need three functions `init`, one is enough. Simply pass the file name parameter.
- don't use big static arrays, like `string first[SIZE]` - this will cause stack overflow. Use vectors instead.
- some bugs are fixed and not compiled lines such as `int random[left];`
- you don't need `random` array at all

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

const size_t SIZE = 50000;
using strings = std::vector<std::string>; // 'array' of strings with dynamic size

void initFromFile(const std::string &fname, strings &arr)
{
    std::ifstream file(fname);
    std::string line;

    while(getline(file, line))
        arr.push_back(line);

    size_t n = arr.size();
    if(n == 0)
        return;
    for(auto i = 0; i < SIZE-n; i++)
        arr.push_back(arr[rand() % n]);
}


int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    srand(time(NULL));
    strings first, middle, last;

    initFromFile("names.txt", first);
    initFromFile("first-names.txt", middle);
    initFromFile("middle-names.txt", last);    

    for(auto i = 0U; i < first.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << first[i] << endl << middle[i] << endl << last[i] << endl;
        cout << "Full Name" << endl;
        cout << first[i] << " " << middle[i] << " " << last[i] << endl; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: `rand` is not guaranteed to produce numbers over 32767. This shouldbn't be a problem for the asker because variable length arrays are usually a signature of g++  and g++ gives a much larger range of `rand` output, but if you're adapting this answer to Visual Studio, watch out!

Comment: @user4581301 Where is `rand`? There is `rand()%n`

Comment: That's the `rand`. The point is `rand` doesn't necessarily go up to 50000. You may not be able to generate the full range of required values.

Comment: @user4581301 In the context of this task, it does not matter. This only affects shuffling algorithm, which is not the essence of the question. And this is an OP's algorithm of shuffling.

Comment: You don't have to talk me into your yourself out of anything. I'm the upvote; I can't do much more than that here. All I'm doing is dropping a warning to future askers with similar problems.

Comment: @snake_style So one problem I am still having is that even with your example (thanks for showing a better way), it still doesn't want to print in the format that I want which is `first middle last`. I do the `for` loop with `auto` and inside is `cout << first[i] << " " << middle[i] << " " << last[i] << endl;` and it outputs the first name, middle name, last name in 3 lines and repeats. So not all of them are in a single line. Basically does `endl` after every output.

Comment: nvm. I figured it out. Something is wrong with the txt files I believe. because of them I am getting some crazy problems. I created new text files and input different things in by hand and it worked correctly. I guess thats what you get when you download a random file a of names hah.